# Curl Effect on UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I would like to know if I can configure the PartialCurl transition effect on a UIViewController. I'm using something like:

```
theConfigCtrler.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
[self presentModalViewController:theConfigCtrler animated:YES];
```

But it hides 90% of the previous view and I can't come back to the previous view. It also changes my device orientation.

I'm trying to build a view where some data is displayed and I want to curl just the half of the view to show another view with some extra information where user can change some data.

Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

make sure the size of your view which you're displaying under the curl has frame size that reflects how much curl you want. As the curl is calculated from the size of this view.

Answer (score 0):

Please search for "Leaves" in GitHub, you will find a project which implements curl effect just like iBook